# Page builder in custom form can't apply template or configure element

Tags: adminform, magento2.4.3, page-builder

I have added a page builder field to my admin form but it seems I can't apply any templates (the dialog doesn't show up and neither do any errors) and configure any elements (same behaviour). I can save templates no problem.

The code for the form element:

```
<field name="short_content" formElement="wysiwyg" sortOrder="10">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Category</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <additionalClasses>
            <class name="admin__field-wide">true</class>
        </additionalClasses>
        <label translate="true">Short Content</label>
        <dataScope>short_content</dataScope>
    </settings>
    <formElements>
        <wysiwyg>
            <settings>
                <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
            </settings>
        </wysiwyg>
    </formElements>
</field>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out to get the modals for the page builder loaded you need to add `<update handle="editor"/>` to the corresponding layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <update handle="editor"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="post_form"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```